# Why time period of GPS PPS signal is not accurately equal to 1 second. (7 to 10 mirco sec less)

Tags: gps

I've multiple nxp K60 controller running at different ppm crystals. All have a GPS modules, i want to adjust their clocks using pps signal from gps.
Whenever K60 controller will start it will adjust their clock by taking reference from pps signal.

But the pps signal time period is not equal to 1 sec. First pps time period is **0.99999270** (7.3 usec less) and after first pulse it goes more less for some time.All positive edge of pps signal on different module is alligned within 1 usec. The time period for raising edge of pps is 0.8usec.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered the accuracy of your measurement device? It seems to be some form of computer-based bit of kit - unless it has it's own precision reference, 7.3 us seems to be a reasonable error.

Comment: It very much depends on the firmware in your GPS Rx. This might help: http://mtnstormdaq.com/blog/2012/10/gps-pps-use-as-a-time-reference/

Comment: Joren has it. What device are you using to measure the period of the pps signal?

Comment: Your GPS clock is probably 100 times more accurate than your Saelae analyser. A cheap crystal oscillator can easily be 10 ppm off frequency. A GPS PPS probably has an error under 0.1 us. Take a look at https://www.febo.com/pipermail/time-nuts/2006-August/021628.html and http://www.leapsecond.com/pages/m12/sawtooth.htm  So you are measuring the error in the logic analyser's clock.

Comment: I'm using Saleae pro 16. I've tried to measured it with oscilloscope (Agilent InfiniiVision 2000 X-Series) but with bigger window of 2s sample rate goes down. so couldn't find a way to measure gps pps accurately.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitively your computer clock that is inaccurate as you are using the Salae Logic Analyzer software.

7ppm is within the expected precision bounds for your computer clock's crystal.

You can expect the GPS clock of a commercial receiver to have an accuracy that is better than 1us - and I think that this is short and long term jitter accuracy.  The (absolute) precision actually depends on your receiver and meteorologic conditions.

More or less every 18 months, UTC time is adjusted so that a leaps seconds must be taken into account to convert the GPS clock to UTC time.
That is due to earth turning slower and slower.  This the precision of a second as these leap seconds only synchronise our calendar with the rotation of the earth.

Comment: Leap seconds have nothing to do with it, unless you're using the logic analyser to measure the rotation of the earth. GPS time and UTC differ by an *integer* number of seconds. No ppm there. See http://www.leapsecond.com/java/gpsclock.htm

Comment: @tomnexus Actually GPS time does differ from UTC very slightly; typically < 30 ns. But your point is still correct- leap seconds have nothing to do with this. GPS time doesn't leap; only UTC does. And the 1PPS in either timescale is unaffected by leap - only the time of day is.

Comment: I've updated the text.  **  It could be misread as the GPS time being corrected. ** I removed my mistake about applying the correction for a calender year to the precision of seconds.

Comment: Please never mention leap seconds. I hate it and it must be purged from our current time standards, and in the future I'm sure it will be looked upon as a big mistake.

Comment: Rendez-vous in 2023 - "a report will be considered by the World Radiocommunication Conference in 2023." - untill then leap seconds are maintained.  **  I agree that they are currently not very usefull because the variation is very small.  If the adjustment would be 15 minutes every year, then it would be different.  **  In the mean time we have to live with the time references that are defined and used.